# How to define a n x 3 large array and add elements to it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and I'm not too familiar with how `ArrayList` works. I want to make a 2D array of size `nx3`. I was thinking something like `ArrayList< array_of_size_3_of_integers>` but I don't know how to define the thing on the inside.

How can I add an array of 3 integers into my `ArrayList`?

Also, is this the right method?

From what I understand, the thing in `< >` must be an object. I tried doing `ArrayList< int[3] >` and `ArrayList< Integer[3]>` but it doesn't work. This probably looks very trivial but I'm struggling.

Comment: if the 2d array does not need to grow at run time. you are better off with a two dimensional primitive array `int[][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, it's not possible. If you want to be safe, that there are only 3 integers in every list-entry i would made a wrapper-class which contains only three integers or something like that.

```
public class ThreeInt {
int a,b,c; //or an array
}
```

The List should be declared like that:

```
List<ThreeInt> list = new ArrayList<ThreeInt>();
```

If you know the size of the second dimension and the time when you initialize the List you can better use an two dimensional array:

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][3];
```

Inside the < > (generics) has to be a Type. Then the compiler only let you insert Objects (or subclasses) of this Type into this List. If it is an interface you can put in all Types which implements that interface.

Comment: Creating a wrapper class worked very nicely, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to keep the idea of using ArrayList**

So let's say you have your arrays here:

```
int[] firstArray = new int[3];
int[] secondArray = new int[3];
```

we don't fill them in this example, we only want them to exist.
Now you want to store them in an `ArrayList`. And you are right, you have to define your ArrayList with these things: `< >`. Inside these you put the **Type** of the objects you want to store in the ArrayList (not the objects themselves). In your case it's `int[]`.

```
ArrayList<int[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
           ^                                 ^
  here you tell the list what type it has    here it is implicit
```

and there you go

```
myArrayList.add(firstArray);
myArrayList.add(secondArray);
```

Comment: Can I do `ArrayList<int[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<int[3]>(); ` if I know that all arrays will be length 3? Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: In `ArrayList<int[]>`  you only define the type of the objects in the list. But you don't actually initialize the objects. `int[3]` is the initialization of an `int[]`. It tells the compiler that your array can have a maximum of 3 elements, at that point the array actually exists (and you can fill it with ints). The same goes for the ArrayList.  With `new ArrayList<>()`  you tell java that you now want your list to exist. But it will still be empty.

Comment: So, no, it won't work. Sorry. If you want to initialize your list directly in one single command you could write something like this: `ArrayList<int[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[3],new int[2]));` then your ArraList has two freshly initialized arrays in it, the first could hold 3 ints and the second 2. But that is just unnecessary und ugly (IMHO).